# Facebook Like button - live update?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is there any way to receive live / streamed updated values for the Like button (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) ? For instance, Facebook's 'Live Stream' (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream/) allows you to see comments 'live' as they're posted. Is it possible to see 'Like' values updated in real time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can add the domain [here](https://www.facebook.com/insights/) and see the stats there

2) You can check these plugins [like box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) and [Activity feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/)

3) You can run a script to get the data frequently

```
FB.api({
                method: 'fql.query',
                query: 'SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://www.facebook.com"'
            }, function(response){});
```